# What caused the "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." warning?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have searched around but it's all about people complaining the bug. Many posts say that you should check all your extensions.

However, this is something I encountered when I am developing an extension.

Here is how it happens:

I have a listener on `background.js`:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('get:', request);
  if (request.hasOwnProperty('opt')) {
    trackPage('opt/' + request.opt);
  }
  return Promise.resolve("");
});
```

And here is the trigger in my option page:

```
track('something');
function track(msg){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({opt: msg}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

The error occurs when the `track` function is fired.

How can I fix the error totally?

Comment: Chrome extensions API doesn't support Promises. Either use the API the way it's shown in the documentation or switch to the modern way with Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill.

Comment: Would you please share more information about the two ways? Thanks!

Comment: I thought you would google up the keywords I gave. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). The [polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill).

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: not yet. just give up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a `Promise` to make the function `async`, you have to return `true`.  So change this:

```js
return Promise.resolve("");
```

To this:

```js
Promise.resolve("").then(result => sendResponse(result));
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why all the "it's Chrome extensions" responses are down-graded.  I turned off all extensions; problem gone.  Tried different browsers (even Microsoft); no problem.  Back to Chrome and turned one extension back on; problem returned. Tried with a simple web page: <?php ; (yes, nothing) problem persists.

So, fuggedaboudit.  Or, quoting Bill Murray in "Meatballs," "It just doesn't matter!"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just replaced the old chrome apis which were inside a Promise with [updated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage) ones:

Old:

```js
  sendMessageToTab: (tabId, msg) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => global.chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg, resolve));
  },
```

The updated ones:

```js
sendMessageToTab: (tabId, msg) => global.chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you see this error on other websites too then don't be bothered because it's not generated by your app, probably some Chrome Extension.

Comment: It's about my extension. It's not about other app/websites.

Comment: @darkrose1977 Yes I'm also saying that it is about chrome extension.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled Tampermonkey Chrome extension and the error disappeared.

Answer (score -2):

check extentions chrome, update or remove or deactive

Comment: Please include more details - what exactly should the OP be updating or removing?

Comment: no more details - with deactived an extention worked me - no error -- https://stackoverflow.com/users/13736952/m-chen-3